# Kafka Consumer Error

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I am using a kafka produer and a Spring kafka consumer. I am using a Json serializer and deserializer. Whenever I try to read messages in the consumer from the topic i get the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition fan_topic-0 at offset 154. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No type information in headers and no default type provided
```

I have not configured anything about headers neither in the producer nor in the consumer. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you are missing the fact that `JsonDeserializer` has to be configured on the `ConsumerFactory` with an appropriate default type to deserialize, but not in the Kafka properties.

All the info is presented in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#serdes

Comment: Adding JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE in properties fixed the issue.

Comment: What if I use EmbeddedKafka to do a simple test where all configurations are put in yaml file? In this case the `CosumerFactory` bean is constructed all by yaml, not by me; I don't want to the overhead of repeating all info in yaml in `config` and pass it to the constructor of consumerFactory only to provide the type info.

Answer (score 1):

just adding to above answer,

The below changes solved for me.

```
config.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
```

adding

```
return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(String.class));
```

instead of

```
return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String>(config);
```

For reference,

the below method in `deserialize` expecting the headers and "`Assert.state..`" throws `IllegalStateException`

```
 @Override
        public T deserialize(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data) {
            JavaType javaType = this.typeMapper.toJavaType(headers);
            if (javaType == null) {
                Assert.state(this.targetType != null, "No type information in headers and no default type provided");
                return deserialize(topic, data);
            }
            else {
                try {
                    return this.objectMapper.readerFor(javaType).readValue(data);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new SerializationException("Can't deserialize data [" + Arrays.toString(data) +
                            "] from topic [" + topic + "]", e);
                }
            }
        }
```